# Can I put more content on iPhone 5 than on Iphone 4?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, autolayout

I am developing an app and in one of the views the 4inch screen would fit the content I want to include just fine but the 3.5 inch screen is just too small so I wanted to remove a part of the content for that screen size.
 So the question is: Do apple allow the bigger screens to have more content than the smaller screens? I guess this question also applies to ipad vs iphone, iphone 6 vs iphone 5 , etc...
 I have never seen this even being discussed and I've never done it myself but always wondered.
 Naturally I would do it in a way that the 3.5 inch screen wouldn't miss anything too important and in a way that the content would be completely hidden on the iphone 4 and the design doesn't suffer. In this particular case I would just remove an ad for another app so the iphone 4 users would probably thank me ;)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This isn't really a programming question the way SO defines it, but I'll take pity on you since you're new.

Yes of course. You always have to tailor your UI for the target device. That often means stripping away non-essential elements from smaller screens.

For iPhone vs. iPad it usually means presenting more on one screen on iPad and multiple screens on iPhone.

Comment: Ok great thanks for the quick reply. I will read more about SO's rules now then.